# Group homomorphism $f$ is surjective iff $g$ is

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an additive group, and let $u, v:G\to G$ to be two endomorphisms. Define $f(x) = x- v(u(x))$ and $g(x) = x-u(v(x))$. The question is to show that $f$ is surjective iff $g$ is.

I'm only able to show that $u:\ker f\cong \ker g$, but unable to show the statement needed. Observe that $u(f(x)) = g(u(x))$ and $v(g(x)) = f(v(x))$.

Comment: Is $G$ assumed to be abelian?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti No.

Comment: The term "additive" normally implies abelian.

Comment: Just a trivial remark. A well-known exercise states that if $R$ is a unital ring, and $u, v \in R$, then $1-uv$ is invertible iff $1-vu$ is. So if $G$ is abelian, and we upgrade surjective with bijective, there we are.

Comment: @Andreas: This was exactly my idea - it leads to a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have the following general fact: In a ring $R$ (not assumed to be commutative) with elements $u,v$, if $1-uv$ is invertible, then $1-vu$ is invertible. In fact, one checks that

$(1-vu)^{-1} = 1 + v (1-uv)^{-1} u$

(This formula has a nice motivation using the geometric series.)

We may apply this to the ring $R=\mathrm{End}(G)$ for an abelian group $G$ (with $1=\mathrm{id}_G$) and see that $1-uv$ is an isomorphism if and only if $1- v u$ is an isomorphism.

But we can also use the formula above to prove that $1-vu$ is surjective when $1-uv$ is surjective:

Let $g \in G$. Choose some $h \in G$ with $(1-uv)(h) = u(g)$, i.e. $h - u(v(h))=u(g)$. Then $g + v(h) \in G$ satisfies
$$(1-vu)(g + v(h))=g + v(h) - v(u(g+v(h)))=g + v(h - u(v(h)) - u(g))=g.$$

This proof also works when $G$ is not abelian (where $x-y$ abbreviates $x+(-y)$ and we use $-(x+y)=(-y)+(-x)$ in the calculation).

Comment: What's the motivation using the geometric series?

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-vu} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (vu)^k = 1 + v \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (uv)^k u = 1 + v \frac{1}{1-uv} u$.